# Destination host not receive UDP message from source host using TIdUDPServer.Send

Tags: delphi, indy

I use `TIdUDPServer` in this scenario:

Host 192.168.1.10: `IdUDPServer1.Active := True` using dynamic port (e.g.: `60112`)

Host 192.168.1.20: `IdUDPServer2.Active := True` using dynamic port (e.g.: `50332`)

When I invoke `IdUDPServer1.Send('192.168.1.20', 50332, 'Hello')`, the host 
`192.168.1.20` didn't receive any UDP message.

I then invoke `IdUDPServer2.Send('192.168.1.10', 60112, 'Hello')`, the host `192.168.1.10` receive the UDP message.  Both hosts are able to receive UDP messages from each other then.

Similarly, if I send message from IdUDPServer2 first, the IdUDPServer1 will not receive any UDP message.

This strange problem always happens to UDP server that first send a message.

This problem doesn't happen if both `IdUDPServer1` and `IdUDPServer2` started in same host (e.g.: localhost or same pc).

I didn't assign any port number to both `TIdUDPServer` instance and let the library to assign a dynamic port for me.  Hence, Windows 10 didn't prompt any Firewall warning.

Comment: How are you configuring the `TIdUDPServer.Bindings` collection on each server? When you call `TIdUDPServer.Send()`, it sends out the packet using the 1st `TIdSocketHandle` object in the `Bindings` collection.  So, if the `.10` server's 1st binding is not bound to the same network that that the `.20` server is listening on, that could explain why it does not receive the packet. Or, if the `.20` server is behind a NAT/firewall, that could be blocking inbound packets from `.10` until `.20` sends out a packet to `.10` first. And vice versa

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I didn't configure `TIdUDPServer.Bindings`,  I leave it as default, it should be empty initially.  Both `.10` and `.20` host are in same LAN.

Comment: If you don't configure the `Bindings` at all, `TIdUDPServer` creates default bindings for you (one for IPv4 and one for IPv6 if the OS supports both). Each binding is bound to all available network interfaces on the `DefaultPort`. So, `IdUDPServer1` will have an IPv4 binding and a IPv6 binding, both bound to port 60112. If you then try to `Send()` a packet, and you are connected to multiple networks, you don't know which network the OS picks, or even which IP version it uses. You should make sure `TIdUDPServer` is bound to the specific network and IP version you want to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I have tried to disable all network adapter and left only one ethernet adapter, I also disable ipv6.  I make sure only one network address were bound using `ipconfig /all`.  I face the same problem too.  I then try to bind the fixed IP address to both the `.10` and `.20` host when start the UDP server.  I also face the same problem too.

Comment: verify with Wireshark if any packets are actually being sent over the LAN, and with the correct information. Either you are not sending what the other server is expecting, or the packets are being blocked by router/firewall

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I found out the the problem why the UDP packet was lost at first time.  It was the Windows Firewall setting.  Windows Firewall block all inbound packet by default.  As I am using dynamic UDP port allocated by TIdUDPServer, surprisingly the Windows firewall didn't notify me anything about the firewall setting.  The first UDP packet sent from `.10` to `.20` did reach the host `.20` by monitoring via `Wireshark` but it didn't  reach `.20` of `TIdUDPServer` instance.  if I set allow all inbound connections by default in firewall, TIdUDPServer of host `.20` receive the UDP packet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I haven't figure out the why first UDP packet from `.10:50332` to `.20:60112` was blocked, followed by `.20:60112` to `.10:50332` will allow, and the subsequence from both hosts will become allow thereafter.

Comment: that's how firewalls work. The firewall on `.20` blocked the inbound packet to `.20:60112` since it was a new packet for an unknown communication, then the firewall allowed the outbound packet to `.10:50332`, at which point it took note that `.20:60112` was communicating with `.10:50332` so the next inbound packet from `.10:50332` was allowed. Since UDP is connectionless, a firewall will usually block inbound packets until it sees an outbound packet first.